# Advice for debugging a network interface?

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli

I'm working on an embedded device running Ubuntu 14.04.

When I first logged in I had no problem using `nmcli dev wifi` and it would return 3 results. *(Though the wifi card must be weak as my laptop returns over 20 results.)*

I then used:

```
nmcli nm wifi off
rfkill unlock wlan
```

Followed by running a wifi AP with `hostapd`, which was successful.

I then turned AP off and ran `nmcli nm wifi on` and restarted the device.

After restarting the `nmcli dev wifi` command "works" *(no errors)* but returns no networks.

Does anyone have any ideas of steps I can take to get more information on the state of the network interface or wifi card?

Comment: please add the wifi chipset. iot board? chinese? realtek+usb?

Comment: It's a custom rockchip board

Comment: I've noticed that with some rare wifi cards, you sometimes need to reload the driver after running it in AP mode to be able to run in client mode again.  Perhaps doing so here might help?

Comment: First thing I'd do is to take network manager out of the equation, configure the device directly with `iw`, `ip` and `wpa_supplicant` (if necessary), and see what happens. Also, have a close look at `dmesg` to spot potential misbehaviour, either upon boot or when configuring something.

Comment: @dirkt thanks I ended up working around the issue by using `iwlist`, the interface had no problem scanning once I started using `iwlist`.

Comment: BTW, `iwlist` is the old utility; the current one is `iw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem by using `iwlist scan` instead of `nmcli dev wifi`.

*Somewhat related information but not specific to interfaces:*

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50099/16792