# No Internet after grub update. Firmware problem?

Tags: linux, grub2, ethernet, internet, firmware

I have a problem and I hope someone can help me.
I installed Debian 11 with a UEIFI installation. During the installation I had to provide the firmware for a Realtek network card. After I booted into the system everything worked fine. I rebooted and the system got stucked.
I searched for this problem and found that I had to edit the file

/etc/defaults

And add nomodeset to the boot options.

Then, apt-upgrade grub.

The problem comes here. Now the reboot doesn't get stuck but I have no internet. This computer uses Ethernet connection. I checked that everything was ok on the /etc/network/interfaces file. If I revert changes I still have no internet and can't boot into the system.

I suspect that somehow the grub update removed the Realtek firmware. I also found that /sbin stoped being on path for root after the update.

Does someone know how to fix this? I can't use most of the solutions I found online because I don't have access to internet.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50098/linux-network-troubleshooting-and-debugging

Comment: `/sbin` not being on path for root when using `su` happened back in Debian 10 as it transitioned from old `su` from the ancient `shadow` package to the newer `su` implementation of `util-linux`.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-upgrade` does not seem to exist, neither does `/etc/defaults`; the appropriate command after updating `/etc/default/grub` would have been `update-grub`.

If the Debian 11 installer has an internet connection, it will automatically download the most recent updates as part of the installation process. Your up-to-date kernel might -in the absolute worst case- require a different version of the firmware file than the old kernel used by the installer. Please see what `dmesg | grep -i firmware` says, and if it reports any missing files, check if it is the same firmware file requested by the installer, and make sure it is in the expected location under `/lib/firmware`.

You might have to use another OS or computer to download the firmware file from e.g. [from the linux-firmware Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/) (find the file you need, then click "plain" on the right-most column to download it), then use an USB stick or similar to move the firmware file in place to the appropriate directory under `/lib/firmware`.